# Making sure (distributed) caches only store the latest value in a distributed system

Tags: redis, memcached, distributed-system

Let's say I want to use a built-in solution such as Redis or Memcached to cache database rows (as an example), to avoid recurrent costly trips to the database.

For the sake of the argument, let's assume I have a TABLE(id, x, y) and that I want to cache all rows so I never have to read directly from the database.

Questions:

1. Consider the following case: NodeA tries to update a given row's field `x` while NodeB tries to update `y`, then both simultaneously try to update the cache line. If they try to "manually" update the field they just changed to the row in the cache, if we follow the typical last-write-wins, one of the fields is going to be discarded, which is catastrophic. This makes me think I need to always fill the cache's rows with a full row read from the database.
2. But this by itself won't necessarily help me. If NodeA writes to `x` and loads the entire row in memory and then NodeB writes to `y` and reads the entire row in memory, if NodeB writes to the cache before NodeA then NodeB's changes will be overwritten! This makes me believe I need to always somehow version the rows both in the DB and in the cache. Is this the case? Memcached seems to have a compare and set primitive, but I see no such thing in Redis.
3. Even if 1. and 2. are not an issue, I still need to guarantee that my write / read has read-after-write consistency, otherwise it may happen that what I'm reading and intending to put in the cache is not necessarily the most up-to-date version. If that's the case, how can I make sure of this? By requiring w + r > n?

This seems to be a very common use-case, I'd guess it's pretty much a solved problem. What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how Facebook solved the issue with Memcached: http://nil.csail.mit.edu/6.824/2020/papers/memcache-faq.txt.

The idea is to use the concept of a lease: when a request for a cached value is received and there is no data for such key, a lease token (64 bits id) is returned.

When the webserver fetches the data from the database it can then store the data in the cache with that token. Every time an invalidation request is invoked on a key, a new lease token is created, and as such, if a put is attempted for an old token, the put ends up rejected.

As far as I understand, it's not really possible to (easily) replicate this behavior with Redis without resorting to LUA scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Key value stores as redis support advance data structures, such as HASHs.

If you're doing partial updates to cached entities (only a set of fields is updated as part of the super set), and given your goal is to avoid time-consuming database reads, simply save the table entry as a HASH K/V pairs (using HSET) and the use HGETALL for reading.

Redis OPS are atomic by nature, so that should solve your problems, if I got them right.

On a side note, if you're caching an entire entity yet doing partial updates, you should consider a simpler caching approach, such as read-through (making cache validity a reader-only concern).

As opposed to Database accesses. Redis cache access from different location unless somehow serialized, will always have the potential of being out of order when it comes to distributed systems, as there's always the execution environment (network, threading) to introduce possible delays.

Doing read-through caching will ensure data is always updated after the most recent write without the need to synchronize anything else.

Comment: Hi. Even if I were to have the row be stored field by field in Redis, the same problem would happen if I had two guys updating the same field at the same time: how could I guarantee that the field that got written last to the database is also the one that got written last to the cache?

Comment: Well, putting the cache aside, if you have two people updating the same entity simultaneously with different values - which one should persist? The same logic should apply to your caching solution. You can also use Redis to create and acquire global locks using SET_NX ...

Comment: Well, it should persist whatever is written in the database, as the goal is to keep the database and cache sync'ed. That's why I referred to versioned rows. SET_NX is useless in this case, as it would not deal with already existing rows.

Comment: My current understanding regarding Redis is that once I write to the DB, I need to request the full updated row (that includes a version-id). I then need to issue a MULTI command to redis, WATCH the variable, fetch Redis' row version and check against the version I got from the DB. If the DB's version is more recent, I can then update the cache, if not I just abort the transaction.

Comment: Another alternative seems to be using a LUA script..

Comment: Again, invalidating the cache after each write and have the reader do cache read-through would ensure the cache is always up-2-date with the latest data, and is also much simpler to maintain then write-based updates.

Access to Redis will always be serialized at some point. even with MULTI-EXEC you are facing possible race condition behavior, because it's possible that later writer was the first to update cache entry in its entirety. You are facing a race condition arising from the fact distributed accesses to redis are not coordinated in anyway, except from being serialized.

Comment: Using a row version in MULTI-EXEC can also cause data to be inconsistent, If you're updating different fields. 

Read through cache is the solution, IMO.

Comment: The read-through approach is not safe: consider 2 writers and 2 readers. `WriterA` writes `W1` to the DB and invalidates the cache. `ReaderA` comes and fetches `W1` from the DB. `WriterB` writes `W2` to the DB and invalidates the cache. `ReaderB` also finds the cache empty, reads `W2` from the DB and writes `W2` to the cache. `WriterA` then writes `W1` to the cache. We're stuck with a stale version of the data in the cache.

Comment: Why does `WriterA` write `W1` to the Cache? that misses the whole point of being "read-through"...

Comment: Correct. As it is, Redis / memcache can be only used as a cache-aside, which makes this whole discussion, as is, completely worthless. This is how facebook solved the issue with Memcached: http://nil.csail.mit.edu/6.824/2020/papers/memcache-faq.txt.